# Create a proxy class with a no-arg constructor

Tags: java, reflection, proxy

Using a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, I can create a class that takes an `InvocationHandler` as constructor argument. However, the class will be instantiated via `newInstance()` somewhere in the framework, and the `InvocationHandler` can be the same for all instances.

Can I add a no-arg constructor to the proxy class, which passes my `InvocationHandler` to the original constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it won't work hat way, as the actual proxy magic happens in this native code

```
private static native Class defineClass0(ClassLoader loader, String name,
                     byte[] b, int off, int len);
```

that's only accessed through the static Method `Proxy.newProxyInstance(ClassLoader, Class<?>[], InvocationHandler)`. This method in turn calls the constructor of the thusly generated class with the supplied `InvocationHandler` as parameter.

So there's no way for you to return a Proxy from a `newInstance()` call. The closest you can get is to instantiate the `InvocationHandler` with `newInstance()` and pass it to the static factory method.

Or you could take the whole thing one step further, have a Class that implements he target interface(s), constructs a proxy field through the factory method and delegates all interface methods to the Proxy. But that would be a proxy around a proxy, and I really don't see the point of that.

Comment: Is there any way to check out that native code for defineClass0?

Comment: @RawAliasCoder That code will be JRE and platform specific, so you would need an insanely good reason to consider changing it - not a route I would choose.